# VB.net - Create a user group?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to create a user group named `Maintenance_app` using vb.net.

The code is:

```
Dim dom As New DirectoryEntry()
  Dim ou As DirectoryEntry = dom.Children.Find("")
  Dim grp As DirectoryEntry = ou.Children.Add("Maintenance_app", "group")
  grp.CommitChanges()
```

I receive the following error at the second line:

`An unknown directory object was requested`

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with Active Directory you need to understand the [LDAP ADsPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746384(v=vs.85).aspx).

In your case:

```
Dim dom as New DirectoryEntry
Dim ou as DirectoryEntry = dom.Children.Find("OU=yourOU")
Dim grp as DirectoryEntry = ou.Children.Add("CN=Maintenance_app", group")
grp.CommitChanges()
```

Or if you want the group on top level without an OU then just erase the 2nd line and change the 3rd line to:

```
Dim grp as DirectoryEntry = dom.Children.Add("CN=Maintenance_app", group")
```

As it seems that you are new to Active Directory here some Glossar:

> DN = Distinguished Name
>
> CN = Common Name
>
> OU = Organizational Unit
>
> DC = Domain Component

Formula example:

> DN = "CN=Doe\, John,OU=Employees,OU=London,DC=fabrikam,DC=com"

Every single object in an Active Directory has its own exact DN.

Comment: Thank you ! I still have a minor issue. After  the `CommitChanges` method is called, I receive the following error : `Access is denied`. P.S. I'm running VS as Administrator.

Comment: Are you sure that you are logged in as Domain Admin and not just simply the Desktop Admin?

Comment: I'm logged in a domain, not desktop admin.

Comment: Please check if in your Active Directory in the default folder "Computer" your desktop computer is listed

Comment: There you have the problem. :P your client is not part of the domain