# Adding User to AD Group in VB.Net (2008)

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I needed to add users to Active Directory using VB.  I found code that works (mostly), except for assigning the user to a group.  I'm fairly certain that the code works, I just don't know the format of the group to pass to it.

Given the code (below), and the image of my AD structure (below that), what is the structure of the GroupName passed to the routine to add the user to the group "Level1/All Users/Level 2/A-K"?

TIA

```
Public Shared Sub AddUserToGroup(ByVal de As DirectoryEntry, ByVal deUser As DirectoryEntry, ByVal GroupName As String)
Dim deSearch As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher()
deSearch.SearchRoot = de
deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group) (cn=" & GroupName & "))"
Dim results As SearchResultCollection = deSearch.FindAll()
Dim isGroupMember As Boolean = False
If results.Count > 0 Then
    Dim group As New DirectoryEntry(results(0).Path)
    Dim members As Object = group.Invoke("Members", Nothing)
    For Each member As Object In CType(members, IEnumerable)
        Dim x As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(member)
        Dim name As String = x.Name
        If name <> deUser.Name Then
            isGroupMember = False
        Else
            isGroupMember = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next member
    If (Not isGroupMember) Then
        group.Invoke("Add", New Object() {deUser.Path.ToString()})
    End If
    group.Close()
End If
Return

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I somehow recognize this Sub *grin*. Okey.. so this function was built to  add a user to a Group. Your "A-K" is an Organizational Unit (OU). Please clarify if you want to create a User in this OU or if you really want to add a User to an existing group.

Comment: When I create a user, I open the AD dashboard.  Depending on the user's last name, I navigate to either A-K or L-Z as you see in the image.  Once there, I right click and select "New > User".  At this point the add user dialog pops up and I'm able to add the user.

Now I admit I don't know much about the inner workings of AD, specifically the difference between an OU and a Group.  What I'm trying to do is automate what I have been doing manually.

The code I have works in as much as it creates a user.  The problem is, no matter what I pass as "GroupName", it puts it in the "root" (Level1).

Comment: Okey I understand now what you want. Give me a moment and I'll provide you the code and explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your input from your comment I set up this `Sub` for you.

You havn't clarified the level below `Level2` so I just called it `Level3`.

This function already enables User as a disabled User is useless...

**References:**

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
```

**How to Use:**

```
CreateUser("Doe", "John")
```

**Method:**

```
Public Sub CreateUser(ByVal givenname As String, ByVal surname As String)

    Dim dom As New DirectoryEntry()
    Dim ou As DirectoryEntry = dom.Children.Find("OU=All Users")
    Dim ou2 As DirectoryEntry = ou.Children.Find("OU=Level2")
    Dim ou3 As DirectoryEntry = ou2.Children.Find("OU=Level3")

    Dim firstLetter As String = givenname.Substring(0, 1)
    Dim ou4 As DirectoryEntry

    If firstLetter Like "*[A-K]*" Then
        ou4 = ou3.Children.Find("OU=A-K")
    Else
        ou4 = ou3.Children.Find("OU=L-Z")
    End If

    Dim ADuser As DirectoryEntry = ou4.Children.Add("CN=" & givenname & "\, " & surname, "user")

    ADuser.CommitChanges()

    'The User is now created. Most people forget to enable their users so I'll put it in here too 

    'UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD 0x10000
    Dim exp As Integer = CInt(ADuser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value)
    ADuser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value = exp Or &H1
    ADuser.CommitChanges()
    'UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE 0x0002
    Dim val As Integer = CInt(ADuser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value)
    ADuser.Properties("userAccountControl").Value = val And Not &H2
    ADuser.CommitChanges()


End Sub
```

See my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35792789/vb-net-create-a-user-group/35793571#35793571) post for basic knowledge of interaction with AD and LDAP.

Comment: That was perfect!  Thanks.